# How to check if template type is of another template type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Suppose I have a template class with int parameter:

```
template <int Param>
class myclass
{
    // ...
}
```

And I want to implement, for example, a cast function from one int-parametrized to another:

```
template <int Param, class T>
myclass<Param> myclass_cast(const T& other)
{
    // ... some logic
}
```

How can I statically determine that `T` is a templated class `myclass<N>`? (I can use C++14).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having a template parameter of `T`, you can deduce the parameter of the `myclass` specialization you pass in:

```
template <int Param, int Other>
myclass<Param> myclass_cast (const myclass<Other>& other)
{

}
```

Comment: Oh, great, never guess this :-)

Comment: How will it behave when argument is a template of multiple parameters?

Comment: @teivaz I have only one int parameter, but it is an interesting question

Comment: @teivaz Then you would need to deduce that number of arguments, or make `myclass_cast` a variadic template.